# ASP.NET Core project with NextJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core, next.js, csproj

I've created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with React.js template using Visual Studio 2019

Everything is ok when I run the project as a React.js application. But when I change the application to a NextJS applications, when I run it I gives me the error :

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
(One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests.
The error output was: Error: Could not find a valid build in the 'C:\Users\myname\source\repos\Panel\Panel\ClientApp\.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
```

I can run the app using **npm run dev** but I want to run the app using visual studio on the same port of ASP.NET Core app is run, like the React.js applications.

How can I add commands like **npm run dev** and execute them to run the app on the same port?

Answer (score 3):

You need a reverse proxy in your Startup.cs to point to the script used to start your next.js app. For example:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/nextjs-client";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "dev");
    }
});
```

Comment: This works for dev mode, but is there a similar solution to use nextjs in a single azure app service container with the "next start" script for the "else" case?

Comment: @NateRadebaugh I typically use Docker Compose with an individual dockerfile to prepare nextjs. I am still in development with my current project but I can test it on azure sometime soon.

Comment: Any update on this @DanielMendez? I haven't gotten to a production example yet, but I envisioned this running within a compose file as well. Compose will start the NextJs app with yarn start and then even in production the .net app will proxy to the compose instance of NextJs for all the UI.